# Can a larger well pressure tank stop the main overload from tripping under heavy water use?

Tags: well-pump, capacitor

This has me stumped. 2HP well pump down 700 feet.  Runs fine all winter spring and fall. But in the summer my pool auto top-off sometimes causes the water to run and run. If I also water the lawn,on occasion (not always) the control box main overload trips. I reset it and it could be fine for another month. I bought and installed a new control box for the pump since the run capacitor was more than 10% off.
Same issue yesterday. My well x trol tank is about 35 gallons, and my pump can only supply around 5gpm. At 60psi my drawdown would be around 12 gallons,  so every 4 minutes or so the water gets used up in my holding tank, and the pump 700 feet down comes on and runs for 2 to 3 minutes.
What if I got an 80 gallon well x trol tank with a 30 gallon drawdown? Yes the pump would run longer, but it would also cool down more between cycles, which I'm thinking is the cause of the overload.
Im trying to avoid a new pump cause labor is high,  and it works most of the year, but hate to spend 1000 for an 80 gallon holding tank if that is not the issue. Thanks for reading.

Comment: How many amps is it pulling?  Well, we can derive that actually. What I need to know is what's the breaker value, and how big are the wires?

Comment: Well the breaker isn't tripping, its fine.  The control box has a start overload and a main overload. Its the main overload that requires resetting. Main breaker in my panel stays on.  Hope that helps

Comment: You need to measure the amperage draw and compare to the pump literature rated max amps. You might need a flow restrictor to keep the pump from pulling too much power and overloading itself. Way cheaper than a new pressure tank, too.

Answer (score 0):

My guess at that deep and low of a flow the well may be running out of water.

The 5gpm was the 3 hour flow rate when the home was built it still may be that but pumping for additional hours on end a few gallons difference in tank size will not change the issue.

On my pool when it tops up it is several hundred gallons so even a 100 gallon pressure tank won’t really help, in my area on the rare homes that don’t have 5 gpm we add cisterns and fill them at a lower rate than the well capacity so the system can maintain the flow this eliminates many problems and extends pump life but a booster pump is needed and a tank.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  My pump is a Gould 7gs20, and at 700 plus feet down, the maximum flow is aroung 6gpm according to the flow curve in the Gould literature.  What I'm really thinking is that the constant on and off is causing overheating and overloading.  Just so I understand,  can these things run for 3 hours straight (like an aquarium pump) without an issue? My thought was a bigger pressure tank = less on and off.  No?  Thanks again for any thoughts you can offer!

Comment: Rich it is possible for a constant run with a cistern. But a large pressure tank will only reduce the cycle slightly, there is also the possibility of increasing the cutoff pressure and decreasing the cut in pressure to extend the time. The problem is if you only have a 5GPM pump and turn on more than that in demand the pressure tank will be consumed and the pump controller kicks in when the water is not there to pump (or some do) so your pump can do 6 great, your well can not according to your flow test. Throttle the output at 5 into a cistern this can be like a 1000 gallon pressure tank.